# Screenshot everything on display

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to take a screenshot of absolutely everything that is displayed on the iPhone display, in the same way that pressing the home + power buttons together does. The code I currently have to screenshot is this:

```
func screenShotMethod() {

    //hide UI
    buttonTrigger.hidden = true

    //take screenshot
    let layer = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.layer
    let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, false, scale);

    layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, nil, nil)

    //show UI
    buttonTrigger.hidden = false
}
```

The point is that I am using the camera and putting a picture over any face it detects, and the easiest way to save that to the camera roll is just to hide the UI and screenshot the screen. With this method however, I get a screenshot of the face tracking picture, in the correct position and size, but not of what the camera sees underneath - just white. I am enabling the camera using the CameraEngine framework in the viewDidLoad() like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.cameraEngine.startSession()
```

Is there a better way to screenshot everything to behave like the hardware induced method? Or how could I include what the camera sees in the screenshot?

Thank you!

UPDATE: In case anyone in the future wants to know how I fixed this, because I can't screenshot things I'm not drawing myself, I solved this issue by taking a picture with the camera and setting that image as the background of the view, and then performing the screenshot function and it works!

Comment: The code from that answer is how I'm performing a screenshot at the moment, but the screenshots don't include what the camera sees. Perhaps I need to start the camera session in a UIView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting in iOS 9 it is no longer possible to take a screenshot that includes elements of the screen not drawn by your program. You can only capture your application's views and layers. Apple doesn't expose the function that is triggered by power+home to third party developers.

Comment: Thank you for your response!